# CCLayerGradient is not fading colors smoothly. How to make it smooth?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

Here is the link where it teaches how to create a gradient layer: http://www.pawapps.com/2011/09/01/quick-code-cclayercolor-and-cclayergradient/

As you can see the gradient in not smooth. You can see stripes of colors. Even the author mentions it:

*"So the above gives a nice but not very smooth fade from one color (in this case black) to another color (in this case white) along a particular vector."*

Here is how bad it looks:

[image: ugly stripes of gradient]

How to achieve smooth gradient? I use cocos2d-x 2.2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal in the Simulator, it only renders with 16-bit color depth. It should look good on a device even though it also defaults to a 16-bit framebuffer. I think that's due to display size and quality, specifically due to higher ppi (pixels per inch).

If it does look undesirable on the device you can increase framebuffer color bit depth to 32-bit at the expense of rendering performance (usually a bad tradeoff on mobile devices).

Comment: just in case, how can I increase frmamebuffer color bit depth to 32 bit? Also do you think the tutorial shows the gradient in simulator too? Because you can see stripes there too ans author mentions explicitly.

Comment: i don't know how its done in cocos2d-x, check where the view is created